# JNI library load error

Tags: java, c++, linux, gcc, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile a java class which call a c++ function. I am using Ubuntu and gcc compiler. 
 Here are the files: ---->

JAVA CLASS

```
public class JNIVips {
 static {
  System.loadLibrary("JNIVips"); // JNIVips.dll (Windows) or libJNIVips.so (Unixes)   }

   // Native method declaration
  private native void callMain(String[] argv);

  // Test Driver
   public static void main(String[] args) {
  new JNIVips().callMain(args);  // Invoke native method
 }
}
```

The C++ file looks like this===>

```
#include "JNIVipsImpl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vips/vips>
#include <vips/vips.h>

void callMain (char **argv)
{.........}
```

JNIVipsCpp.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "JNIVipsImpl.h"
#include "JNIVips.h"


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIVips_callMain(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jobjectArray argv )
{
    return callMain();
}
```

JNIVipsImpl.h==>

```
#ifndef _JNI_VIPS_IMPL_H
#define _JNI_VIPS_IMPL_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
 #endif

    void callMain();

  #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
  #endif 

  #endif
```

I am using the following commands in the terminal to compile the code. One by One.

1)  `javac JNIVips.java`

2)   `javah JNIVips`

3)  `g++ -c -I"/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_60/include" -I"/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_60/include    /linux" -Wall JNIVipsImpl.cc 'pkg-config vipsCC --cflags --libs'`

4)`g++ -shared -fPIC -I"/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_60/include" -I"/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_60/include/linux" -o libJNIVips.so -shared -Wl,-soname,libJNIVips.so 'pkg-config vipsCC --cflags --libs'`

I am getting the following error

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class JNIVips]
```

Comment: This is ***not*** a compilation error.

Comment: Make sure that your library can be found. E.g. set `java.library.path` correctly.

Comment: I also suggest you learn how to properly unpack a jobjectArray.  Assuming it is a char** is totally incorrect.

Comment: This might be me missing something, but as far as I can see you are not linking JNIVipsImpl.o and JNIVips.o at all (in your statement 4). Which would explain why the library loaded crashes.

Comment: @user3811300 - Please investigate functions such as `GetObjectArrayElement`, `GetStringUTFChars`, etc.  You cannot merely cast a jobjectArray to a `char**` and believe you have a C-style `char**` containing your arguments.

Comment: When you finally get around to deciding what the actual error message is, please fix your title and your post to express it accurately.

Comment: Now this is my final  code. Was just trying out thing you guys said.

Comment: So how on earth did you go from being to load and execute your Java class, albeit unsuccessfully, to being unable to even find it? And where is JNIVips.h? NB There's only one 'tryout' in your edit, and it doesn't address the problems raised here correctly.